# How to make input correspond with a collection of values, and make a decision based on the input?

Tags: python

The goal here is to write a function called `displayPerson​` that takes in an integer called `id` as its first parameter, and a dictionary as its second parameter, called `personData`.
The purpose of the function is to print the name and birthday of a given user identified by the input id. If there is no entry with the given id, then print “No user found with that id” instead.
The format should be “Person # *id* is *name* with a birthday of
*date*”, where *id* is the id # inputted, and *name* is the name of the person (from the file) and *date* is the birthday of the user (formatted as `YYYY-­MM-­DD`.

This is what I have so far

```
import argparse
import urllib.request
import datetime
import logging

#url https://s3.amazonaws.com/cuny-is211-spring2015/birthdays100.csv
#url = input('Insert URL here: ')

url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cuny-is211-spring2015/birthdays100.csv"

def downloadData(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    #print(data)
    return data

def processData(file_content):
    dictionary = {}
    #print(file_content)
    # [
    #   "1,Charles Paige,06/01/1963",
    #   "2,Andrew Bell,29/03/1972",
    #   ...
    #   "99,Alan Wilson,03/04/1960",
    #   "100,Austin Burgess,04/06/1979"
    # ]


    count = 0
    data_items = file_content.splitlines()
    logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log', filemode='w', level=logging.ERROR)
    for line in data_items[1:]:
        data_pieces = line
        data_pieces = data_pieces.split(',')
        # ["1", "Charles Paige", "06/01/1963"]
        count = count + 1
        #print(data_pieces)
    #   dictionary[data_pieces[0]] = (data_pieces[1]), datetime.datetime.strptime((data_pieces[2]), '%d/%m/%Y')
        try:
            dictionary[data_pieces[0]] = (data_pieces[1]), datetime.datetime.strptime((data_pieces[2]), '%d/%m/%Y')
        except ValueError:
            logging.error("Error processing line #: " + str(count) + " for ID #: " + str(data_pieces[0]))
    return dictionary

def displayPerson(id, personData):
    #print(personData)
    #return
    try:
        id = input("ID:")
        print("Person #" + id + "is" + dictionary[data_pieces[1]] + "with a birthday of" + datetime.datetime.strptime((data_pieces[2]), '%Y-%m-%d'))
    except:
        print("No user ID found")


def main():
    downloadData(url)
    file_content = downloadData(url)
    values = processData(file_content)
    #print(values)
    displayPerson(id, values)
```

When I input an ID number, it raises the except every time. I'm not sure how to format the code to correspond the ID number with the values from the dictionary I created in `processData`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your code will always throw and catch an exception in your `displayPerson` function because `dictionary` and `data_pieces` are not defined inside that function.  If you do `except Exception as ex:` rather than just `except:`, then you can look at the value of `ex` in your debugger or print it out, and you should get information about what is going wrong.  You should use a full-featured Python IDE, like PyCharm (my recommendation) or VS Code with Python configured.  These tools would be showing you that you have undefined variables in your code.

Comment: You are not using the data you pass into `displayPerson`.   I assume that you want to use `personData` rather than `dictionary`.  I have no guess as to where `data_pieces` is supposed to come from.  My guess is that you don't want or need that in your `print` statement at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code all seems to work OK except for the `print` line in your `displayPerson` function. Replace that line with this, and I think you'll get the behavior you're looking for:

```
print("Person #" + id + " is " + personData[id][0] + " with a birthday of " + personData[id][1].strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

When I enter a value of "1", I get the following output:

```
Person #1 is Charles Paige with a birthday of 06/01/1963
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thank you!